# Apply Jinja2 filter to every value in every rendered template

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I'm trying to create a Jinja2 environment with the intention of only using it on JSON templates. Thus, I would like to apply the `tojson` filter on every rendered value. I'm aware that each individual template can use [filter sections](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#id11) but would like to avoid this.

Is there any way to set a global filter? If not, would the next best thing be a custom loader that inserted the filter section at the beginning and end of the loaded data?

Comment: The `tojson` filter is actually from Flask but it is fairly easy to implement your own.

Comment: Filter sections also apply to the whole text, not just the replaced values. So this does not help to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a recursive function to your context dict before you pass it to Jinja2.

For example, this function escape every string inside a dict prepending a `\` to specific characters.

```py
def escape_markdown(data):

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {key: escape_markdown(val) for key, val in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        return re.sub(r'([\\*_])', r'\\\1', data)
    else:
        return data
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I use a helper function to render my templates, which inserts some handy variables as well as being usable for what you need. I understand it's not exactly what you're asking for, but hopefully it will still be useful.

```
def render_response(self, _template, **context):
    # Renders a template and writes the result to the response.
    import json, time
    context['now']=int(time.time())
    context['anything_you_want']=self.session['something']
    for k in context:
        context[k] = json.dumps(context[k])
    rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
    self.response.write(rv)
```